# Regex in sed to remove hyperlink and keep link text

Tags: html, regex, hyperlink, sed

In a mysql dump I want to remove all link tags that contain a certain class and leave the (always just) one word that was enclosed in the tags.

tag structure:

`<a ..potential-other-stuff.. class="lexicon-term" ..potential-other-stuff.. >medium</a>`

This was as far as I got and I know it makes no sense:

`/<a class="lexicon-term" >[^ tab]\+<\/a>/`

Comment: are you certain that your data will always be on the same line? Could the values you're trying to extract contain CR/LF chars? If so, sed (as much as I love it), is not the appropriate tool for manipulating XML like data. Look into using xmlstarlet or other xml specfic tools. There are xml tags here on S.O. with fair number of followers. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

although shellter is right, here's one:

```
xmpl='<a ..potential-other-stuff.. class="lexicon-term" ..potential-other-stuff.. >medium</a>'
echo $s | sed 's|<a [^>]* class="lexicon-term" [^>]*>\([^<]*\)</a>|\1|'
```

some comments:

- sed allows arbitrary delimiters. here `|` is better than `/`.
- `[^>]` instead just `.` stops the pattern from spanning across multiple a-tags

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove 2 spaces, one before 'class' and one after '"lexicon-term"' to get it to work. So: `echo $s | sed 's|<a [^>]*class="lexicon-term"[^>]*>\([^<]*\)</a>|\1|'`

Comment: I promise you'll have to fix other issues in future and that's when you'll agree with @shellter